# Multiple file download and processing with Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, ftp

I have a perl program on serverA, the program needs to process data for around 500 DOM ip's. The DOM files are on serverB. For each DOM i need to download 6 files to some formulas and inserted them on MySQL DB.  For each DOM takes aproximately 2 minutes to download the files. I need to do that in the lowest time possible, because i have to that process aproximately every two hours.

Right now I am using multithreading:

```
    my @threads;
for my $key (keys %dom)   ### Have all DOM ip
{
    print "El key es $key\n";
    my %data = %{$dom{$key}};
    my $t = threads->new(\&sub1, $postD, $preD, $key, $counter, %data);
    push(@threads,$t);

    if($counter == 40)
    {
        foreach (@threads) {
            my $num = $_->join;
            print "done with $num\n";
        }
        $counter = 1;
        @threads=();

    }
    $counter++;

}
foreach (@threads) {
    my $num = $_->join;
    print "done with $num\n";


 sub sub1
 {
my ($postD, $preD, $key, $num, %data) = @_;
my $status = GetRelevantFiles(substr($postD,0,8),substr($preD,0,8),%data) if (!defined($opt_f));

if(ref($status) eq 'ERROR')
{
    warnNotify($status->{'message'});
}
return $num;
 }
```

Sometimes do no bring all the files.

I am doing good or there is another way to do it best??

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. What is a DOM file? What are postD, preD, etc.? Please post real code.

Comment: Hi, This are variables, I cannot put all the code, It is about 1600 lines.

Comment: Sorry, DOM files are the EVDO equipment, i forget to explain

Comment: Karem, the code above is useless to try to help you. Please try to come up with a minimal _working_ example of what you want to do, and some sample input data. Crystal balls aren't that effective. By the way, your answer about DOM files doesn't really answer anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider replacing your threads with [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager)

As for not downloading all of the files:

- Is there a consistency to the number not downloaded?
- Are there any error messages?